# android adb is really slow after a day(Devices are connecting to host all the time)

Tags: android, adb

All my adb commands to some of my connected devices are really slow. The result shows after 1-2 mins. Fow example adb shell will wait 1 min to enter. And it will stuck after enter the adb shell.

This always happened after 1-2 days after reboot these devices and only reboot those devices could solve the problem.(My devices are connecting all the time to host machine)

Restart adb or close/open devices' debug mode or reconnect these devices cannot solve the problem only I could reboot them.

Is there some problems with my android ROM or the bug of the ADB?

Thanks

This only happened on Android 6.0.

Answer (score 11):

First, you can restart adb by,

1. `adb kill-server`
2. `adb start-server`

Second, you should unplug the cable and plug it in again.

And then , test adb response again

Comment: I forgot to mention restart adb cannot solve the problem either. After restart adb, the device become offline and then after about 1-2 mins, it become device and the same problem come back again. I tried all the method only reboot phone could solve it

Comment: For me, Android Studio would take 30s to show my phone after plugging in. Then, launching would be super slow as well. 
I navigated to platform_tools (where adb.exe is) and did `adb devices` which caused a restart, because it recognized different client versions:
`List of devices attached
adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
* daemon started successfully *
1a2b3c4d        device`. Now it's fast again! Maybe this helps somebody.